# Why we have to declare variable outside of if statement in Java

Tags: java, php

In Java, if we run:

```java
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         if (true) {
             int test = 1;
         } else {
             int test = 2;
         }
        System.out.println(test);
     }
}
```

It will throw:

```
HelloWorld.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(test);
                           ^
  symbol:   variable test
  location: class HelloWorld
1 error
```

However, in php, if we run:

```php
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

if (true) {
    $test = 1;
} else {
    $test = 2;
}

echo $test;
```

It will print 1.

I suspect if that is because Java is strong typed language and php is weak typed language. Can someone give a more deep and lower level explanation?

Comment: @JoshuaBurt I am more concerned about why php and Java behave differently. Luckily, one of the answer addresses my puzzle. php is functional scope while Java is blocked scope

Answer (score 3):

In Java, the visibility scope of a variable is limited by `{}`

```
if (true) {
    int test = 1;
} else {
    int test = 2;
}
System.out.println(test);// Will fail to compile
```

It is also important to note the dead code as shown below:

```
int test;
if (true) {
    test = 1;
} else {
    test = 2;// Dead code
}
System.out.println(test);
```

Because of `if (true)` the `else` block will never be executed causing `test = 2` to become the dead code.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with difference between static and dynamic typing. The difference here between Java and PHP is variable scope.

1. In PHP `$test = 1;` will be part of the global scope [as per docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).
2. In Java `int test = 1;` will be part of local scope, in your case limited to `if` block.

Answer (score 2):

Java is "block scoped"; things introduced inside of one { } block go away at the end of that block.

PHP is "function scoped"; things introduced inside of a function last until the end of the function.  If you're not in a function, the variable is a global, and lasts until the program completes.

In both languages, once something falls out of scope, it's garbage collected.